# Proxy classes exposing the wrong type

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontractserializer, svcutil.exe

I have a web service method that expects a parameter of type OnlinePaymentResponse. This type includes a property of type CustomData, like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class OnlinePaymentResponse
{        
   public CustomData CustomData { get; set; }
}
```

CustomData class is like this:

```
[XmlType(Namespace = XmlConstants.Namespace)]
public class CustomData
{
    public CustomData()
    {
        this.Tables = new List<DynamicTable>();
    }

    [XmlElement("DynamicTable")]
    public List<DynamicTable> Tables { get; set; }

    .....
```

Problem is, when I generate the proxy with svcutil.exe, insted of getting the CustomData type I'm getting an array of DynamicTable.

```
public partial class OnlinePaymentResponse
{    
    private DynamicTable[] customDataField;

    ..........
```

I've been playing with it and found that if I remove the XmlElement attribute of the Tables property, it will generate the proxy class properly:

```
public partial class OnlinePaymentResponse
{    
    private CustomData customDataField;

    ..........
```

I don't understand why does it happen. I've been playing with DataContract, DataMember, XmlRoot and other attributes but I haven't been able to get the proxy right without removing the XmlElement attribute. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Svcutil try to generate a class not to be coupled to .NET. type, so an array is a common type that can be use for other platforms.

You can create a with CollectionDataContract attribute (see more here: [CollectionDataContract attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)) and inherits from List, it will generate a complex that is not an array.